# where with two colums time without zone: greatest

Tags: postgresql

I have two columns one is a `time` the other a `timestamp`

```
ALTER TABLE public.tour
    ADD COLUMN reprocess_toupdate timestamp without time zone DEFAULT NOW();
ALTER TABLE public.tour
    ADD COLUMN reprocess_updated time without time zone DEFAULT NOW();
```

when I execute:

```
select reprocess_toupdate, reprocess_updated 
from tour 
where reprocess_toupdate::date > reprocess_updated::date;
```

I get an error:

> ERROR:  cannot cast type time without time zone to date

without `::date`, I get this error:

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone > time without time zone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because a TIME column does not have a date component. It's range of values is 00:00:00 - 24:00:00. see [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) Section 8.5 Date/Time Types. Since it does not have a date component you cannot cast it  as date. The proper solution would to change the type to "timestamp without time zone". If that is not possible then compare just the times or to "reattach" the date then compare:

```
with dateset as
     (select '2019-06-02 13:00:00'::time without time zone tm, (now() - interval '1 day')::timestamp without time zone dt)
select tm, dt, date_trunc('day', dt)+tm redt from dateset
```

Answer (score 0):

Works here:

```sql
create temporary table so (id serial primary key, ts timestamp default now());

insert into so (ts) values (now());

select * from so where ts::date < now();
```

Output:

```
+------+----------------------------+
| id   | ts                         |
|------+----------------------------|
| 1    | 2019-07-01 10:16:43.093662 |
+------+----------------------------+
```